# editing an activity, shows contact id instead of name, console has "string literal contains an unescaped line break"

Tags: wordpress, activities, ajax

CiviCRM 5.66.0, Wordpress 6.4.2, php 8.1.12

From a contact's list of activities, or a search list of activities, clicking on the edit link of an activity generates an edit popup that does not populate the contact fields with names, but instead with the (correct) contact id.

The behaviour does not occur when opening the edit in a new window, or when using the link to create a new activity, i.e. it's specific to the popup aspect.

In the browser console, I can see:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: '' string literal contains an unescaped line break
    jQuery 14
    refresh https://crm.kbia.ca/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/js/crm.ajax.js?r=G3vOeen_US:329
    jQuery 5
jquery.min.js:73:10
    jQuery 14
    refresh https://crm.kbia.ca/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/js/crm.ajax.js?r=G3vOeen_US:329
    jQuery 5
```

Comment: Does the person's name have an apostrophe in it? Or are there any ajax network calls that have a 200 response code but the actual response is broken somehow.

Comment: Those are reasonable lines of inquiry, but no.
1. The behaviour applies to all activities (at least those tested, not including the sheep painted white on one side).
2. Network tab in console shows all 200 green.

Comment: BUT there is a custom extension active on this page which might be related, though it's weird that the error does not occur on the non-ajax edit page. Also notable that the error doesn't occur with Microsoft Edge. I guess I should try disabling the extension and see if the error goes away.

Answer (score 1):

At this point, my best guess is that it was due to an update to the divi theme. Specifically, a site development copy isn't exhibiting the behaviour, and that's the difference I can see most readily. Not conclusive.